# Access pre-existing database(read only) from iOS bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb, ios-sqlite

I have pre-created database stored in a folder inside my bundle. Can I access it directly from that folder without copying to Document folder?. I don't want to write anything to Db. Only want to read some data. I am using FMDB framework also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the path to your database using:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

Change the parameters to match your database. And then provide that path to your framework so you can access it.

Comment: Actually i forgot to add the link to 'copy bundle resources'. Its my fault. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: is there a way to do same for android. to access from raw folder ?

Comment: This is another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060140/can-i-open-a-read-alone-database-from-res-asset-folder-in-android-without-copyin/36060296#36060296