# can I open a read alone database from res/asset folder in android without copying to database folder

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-resources

I want to open a database and read some values from asset or resource folder.I don't want to write any data to DB.since my db size is huge I cant copy it to database folder as it will consume lot of time and memory. Any help?

Comment: *it will consume lot of time* how big is a file? *it will consume lot of .. memory* you are so wrong ... in theory 1 byte buffer should be enough to copy a file(of course it would be not efficient, but possible)

Comment: it is nearly 500MB. So I have to consume 1GB for that right? one in resource folder and another one in database folder(that i copies) ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but this is not possible. SQLite cannot work with purely an `InputStream`, which is all you can get from an asset or raw resource. Remember that assets and resources are not files on the device — they are only files on your development machine.